# Defining types in mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, mongoose

For a mongoose schema, is there a difference between `name: String` and `name: { type: String }` when defining types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mongoose, `name: String` is just a shorthand for `name: {type: String}`. Both versions are perfectly valid.